# Is there a cyclic list manipulate function?

Tags: functions, algorithm

I can't seem to find a function that will input x and output y.  For my application, each of the numbers 1,2,3,4 represent a list, and the matrix is much larger.

```
x=[{1,2,3,4}]

y=[{{1,2,3,4},
{2,3,4,1},
{3,4,1,2},
{4,1,2,3}}]
```

Answer (score 10):

Square brackets are only used for functions

```
x = Range[4]

(* {1, 2, 3, 4} *)

y = NestList[RotateLeft, x, Length[x] - 1]

(* {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4, 1}, {3, 4, 1, 2}, {4, 1, 2, 3}} *)
```

If the extra brackets are intended

```
x = {Range[4]}

(* {{1, 2, 3, 4}} *)

y = {NestList[RotateLeft, x[[1]], Length[x[[1]]] - 1]}

(* {{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4, 1}, {3, 4, 1, 2}, {4, 1, 2, 3}}} *)
```

Answer (score 9):

```
Permute[Range[4], CyclicGroup[4]]
```

> ```
>  {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4, 1}, {3, 4, 1, 2}, {4, 1, 2, 3}}
> ```

You can also use [`RotateLeft`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RotateLeft.html):

```
RotateLeft[Range[4], #] & /@ Range[0, 3]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4, 1}, {3, 4, 1, 2}, {4, 1, 2, 3}}
> ```

Comment: CyclicGroup is what I needed.  I'm planning on using a sequence of RGBColor in Colorize, so this works for me: tab = Permute[Tuples[{0, .5, 1}, 3], CyclicGroup[27]]

Answer (score 8):

```
x = Range[4];
Partition[x, Length[x], 1, 1]
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4, 1}, {3, 4, 1, 2}, {4, 1, 2, 3}}